# Copy constructor called instead of Operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I’m trying to do a simple exercise now with a Matrix and I want to implement this operations: Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix c(a), Matrix d = a, Matrix e = a + b. For the moment I keep it simple but later I want to do the same thing, but with dynamic allocation and later with smart pointers.

I declared an explicit copy constructor and I overloaded operator=, I also declared a destructor so I have the rule of three.

Here are my functions:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& opEven)
{
    std::cout << "Operator = " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ORD; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ORD; j++)
        {
            arr1[i][j] = opEven.arr1[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& obj) 
{
    std::cout << "Constructing matrix using copy c-tor." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ORD; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ORD; j++)
        {
            arr1[i][j] = obj.arr1[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I try to use Matrix d = a my compiler use the copy constructor, not my operator=.

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCGu.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call it like

```
Martix a;
Matrix b = a;
```

it always uses copy constructor. Try this:

```
Matrix a;
Matrix b:
b = a;
```

Basically, `Matrix a = b;` and `Matrix a(b);` is the same thing, because you are **constructing** matrix `a` using matrix `b`, so that causes a copy constructor call.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. 
But I have to call it as Matrix b = a and take as operator=

Comment: Well, that's how c++ works, you can't make it use assignment operator when your object has not been constructed yet.

Comment: @Teodor-MarianWolf You can't.  Anything in the form of `Type name = something` will always call the copy constructor.  That is how the language works.